# framework для python

Tags: python, графика, framework

Подскажите пожалуйста framework для python на котором было бы удобно отображать подобные схемы в web. Да и вообще, если перед вами стояла подобная задача то какие бы инструменты вы использовали и почему.

[image: пример схемы]

Comment: почему именно на Python? Я использую django-framework для web, но я однозначно бы не стал использовать для данного интерфейса. Может в связке с javascript это было бы удобоваримо. Это реально сделать, но насколько это приемлимо не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста framework для python на котором было бы удобно
> отображать подобные схемы в web

Для бекенда - любой web framework под python. Хоть Django, хоть FastAPI.
Для фронта - стандартный набор JS и проч. JS библиотека, сюда даже jQuery пойдет.
Кстати, придется использовать websocket т.к. показатели оборудования в АСУшках меняются с некоторым временным интервалом.

Графика в SVG. Есть SVG редакторы в т.ч. для подобных мнемосхем.